# Why did ros prevail?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New to ROS, trying to understand the history of robotic frameworks in general and how this opensource software came to be. So why did ROS prevail over other frameworks. In 2012 trinity researchers had done a study https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6195127 where player stage and mds had better scores but now ros is the standard.
Is it because of OSRF and it taking over ROS in 2013, or what. Would like to know.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316916/why-did-ros-prevail?/) by [shaqdc1](https://answers.ros.org/users/40246/shaqdc1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-03-19**:
@shaqdc1 I don't doubt that this is a duplicate, but a link would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I've seen, ROS has been popular among academics and startup robotic companies for a number of reasons:

- The Willow Garage internship program and PR2 program trained a lot of interns on how to use ROS, and when they went back to their universities, they brought ROS with them and trained the other students in their lab about how to use it.
- Willow Garage put a lot of effort into the documentation and documentation structure for ROS. This makes it easier to get started than competing frameworks. (This is the primary reason why I started using ROS)
- By it's structure, ROS is a federated framework, which makes it easier for developers to use other packages, and easier for developers to release their own work.
- OSRF (and Willow Garage before it) provide pre-compiled binaries to run ROS on Ubuntu. This helps make it easier to install and run ROS.
- There is a large demand for books about ROS, and therefore a reasonable number of books about ROS.
- ROS is (mostly) released under a BSD license that makes it easy for companies to use without worrying about copyright.
- There are a number of other companies building and supporting relatively capable ROS-based robots that are targeted at beginners, including the Turtlebot project and most of the robots that have been released by Clearpath Robotics.

The primary measures for the success of ROS are the number of papers that cite the original workshop about ROS at ICRA 2009, and the number of downloads of the ROS binary packages. I believe OSRF publishes both of these metrics.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-03-01**:
+1 to documentation and accessibility. I would add the existing selection of drivers/bridges and the network effect as another major reason. Few things matter as much to new adopters than "Is this the least painful option that does what I need to do?"

**Comment by [shaqdc1](https://answers.ros.org/users/40246/shaqdc1/) on 2019-03-04**:
@fvd COuld you elaborate what you mean by  existing selection of drivers/bridges and the network effect. I  couldn't quite catch it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-05**:
Drivers: There are lots of good ROS nodes to connect sensors and other hardware to ROS; for example the Hokuyo urg_node, lots of camera drivers, and a variety of mobile bases and actuators.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-05**:
Network effect: since there is already lots of good software written that uses ROS, this encourages further development of software using ROS, since people try to re-use existing drivers and algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been developing robot for about 12 years and using ros for more than 8 years. By the way, I am mechanical background, currently more on programming.

I wrote quite a long essay in Chinese two years ago stating why it is prevail.
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/24780066

I just make an abstract.

- ROS is better than what I used before ROS in communication, visualization, simulation, transportation, community, commercialization, compare with Windows + RTX, IPC, NAOqi, Labview, qnx, etc.
- ROS standardise the message types in robotics. That's why ROS start to thrive. Thanks to Willow Garage.
- Compare with Android (which is more dominant in China for the less functional robot products), ROS definitely has a bright future.

I think if Sebastian is going to remove things from ROS instead of building from scratch, only shows that ROS has its value.

@Sebastian From my opinion, ROS is not designed for embedded system and it is not aim for low level control, though ROS has this feature.

The only thing I agree with Sebastian is that ROS has safty issues, and security issues due to the networking configurations.

Anyway, welcome to have a discussion.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2019-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2019-03-14**:
In your own blog you give an example where it took you days (over a week) just to compile a ROS package: http://tianb03.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-successfully-compile.html

This is not normal. This is terrible software.

> ROS is not designed for embedded system

ROS is designed specifically for ubuntu. This is absurd. It is ridiculous to assume that a robot will be running ubuntu.

And people claim it is possible to get ROS to run on other platforms, but good luck with that. You will probably spend a week with trying to get it to compile.

Embedded systems are extremely important in robotics. Most robotics are embedded systems, or contain them in their components.

> Compare with Android (which is more dominant in China for the less functional robot products), ROS definitely has a bright future.

It sounds like you don't even know what ROS is. It's not comparable to Android. Android is an OS. ROS is not.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2019-03-14**:
ROS is terrible, absurd, ridiculous, and I do not know what ROS is.

I am aware that you cannot read Chinese. again, Anyway, welcome to have a discussion.